# Drupal 7 Search Redirect (similar to the old AOL keyword search)

Tags: search

I've searched around for any pre-existing solutions to tackle this problem but so far nothing obvious. Here is basically what I'm after:

1) User enters keyword(s) via core search box

2) If user enters a specific keyword from a list of pre-determined keywords, redirect them immediately to a specific URL/node, e.g:

```
switch ($keyword) {
    case 'brand a':
        drupal_goto('brands/brand-a');
        break;
    case 'brand b':
        drupal_goto('brands/brand-b');
        break;
    default:
       do a regular keyword search . . .
       break;
endswitch;
```

3) If their keyword doesn't exist in the pre-determined list, shuffle them off to the standard Drupal search

Any ideas on how to best accomplish in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a few you and you don't need any advanced matching you can add a path alias for the search path pointing to the preferred page.

E.g. searching for `brand a` gives you the path `search/node/brand a`. This path you can add as a path alias at `admin/config/search/path/add` pointing to a node of your choice.

For more advanced matching (and a more solid solution) you should probably hook into [`hook_search_preprocess()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/7) and do something along the lines of your example code.

Comment: Thanks both of these worked great -- we actually ended up overriding the core search with a views-based search, and used a views preprocess hook for the redirects and we were able to automate it all by matching terms from a particular vocab and redirecting to the relevant taxonomy term panel.